# Is $O(T+\log T)= O(T\log T)$?

Tags: asymptotics

Is $O(T+\log T)= O(T\log T)$?

I think this is true but I do not know how to show it mathematically?

Please show it using the definition.

Also, if it is true, is the following true?

$O((T+\log T)^{1/n})= O((T\log T)^{1/n})$

Comment: What makes you think it may be true?

Comment: "Please show it using the definition." What *definition* are you talking about? I know at least three common ones for $O(\cdot)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b$ be the base of the logarithm. If $T > \max(b^2, 2)$, then $\log T =\log_b T> 2$. So 
$$T\log T - (T+\log T) = (T-1)(\log T -1) -1 > 1\times 1 -1 =0$$ 
i.e., $T+\log T< T\log T$.

So, any function that grows asymptotically slower than $T+\log T$ modulo a constant factor also grows asymptotically slower than $T\log T$ modulo the same constant factor. According to [the definition of multiple usages of big O-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big%5FO%5Fnotation#Multiple%5Fusages), 
$$O(T+\log T)= O(T\log T)$$

Yes, it is true that $O((T+\log T)^{1/n})= O((T\log T)^{1/n})$, where we consider $n$ as a constant.

Comment: The last $1$ in the r.h.s of the first equality should be $-1$. It works for $t \geq 4$ when $\log$ is natural logarithm and $t \geq 15$ when the base is $10$.

Comment: Sorry for my typo. I updated my answer (without seeing your comment.)

Comment: @Saeed Note the abuse of notation here. While "O(n + log n) = O(n log n)" is wrong, mathematically speaking, "=" is often supposed to be read as "$\subseteq$" in this context.

Comment: @ Raphael: Good point. thank you. I didn't know that. Shall I use, say $O(n) \subseteq O(n+1)$ instead of $O(n) =O(n+1)$?

Comment: Both are fine, while the former might be easier to accept. You may want to check this question, [O(·) is not a function, so how can a function be equal to it?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/101324/o-is-not-a-function-so-how-can-a-function-be-equal-to-it/101368#101368), which has several nice answers. @Raphael's comment above is along the line of most popular answers over there, while my answer over there emphasizes a different perspective of the situation.

Comment: A better example is $O(n)\subseteq O(n^2)$ since $O(n)$ is really the same as $O(n+1)$. $O(n)\subseteq O(n+1)$ and $O(n+1)\subseteq O(n)$. When you use the set-theoretic notation, $\subseteq$, it looks like less ambiguous. In contrast, the equality symbol in $O(n)=O(n^2)$ does not mean equality; its meaning is defined by [that definition of multiple usages of big O-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple%5Fusages)

Comment: @Saeed $O(n) = O(n+1)$ is actually _true_; both are the same function class. I suggest you check out the definitions again and observe how Landau symbols define sets of functions. The rest follows.